# Twitch API get viewer count

Tags: c#, json, api, twitch

I want to use the link http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/dreamhackcs/chatters for fetching the information about the channel. As you can see, it gives back a JSON response, but I only want the "chatter_count" number.

How can I go about fetching only that data from the web-response? I have never used an API for fetching data before. I just need to get the chatter_count to be a int or string value.

Comment: [json2csharp.com](https://json2csharp.com).

Comment: I've look at this, what do I do with the data after that, like how do I feed it the information to fill the lists?

Comment: Please [do not put "Solved" in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/detect-edits-to-add-solved-or-resolved-to-the-title-and-direct-the-user-to-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the string to a JObject using Json.Net.

You can do this with: `JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(yourJsonString)`

Then use:
`int chatters = (int)jObject["chatter_count"]`

that should get your lucky number

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! You are a God among men! I've been trying to figure this out for over 2 hours now! Thank you so much

Comment: If it works don't forget to accept the answer. Also if you ever need to get a class from a Json string(since you are using 3rd party software) you might find a funny option in visual studio. Under `edit-->Paste special`.